# Extract information from rows that are connected to each other with id

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In sqlite, There is a table called pathparts This table contains 3 columns

```
rowId | parent | pathpart
```

The rows are as follows

```
rowId | parent | pathpart
--------------------------
1     | null   | manifests
100   | 1      | h
154   | 100    | publisher
184   | 154    | appname
654   | 184    | version
985   | 654    | url
1452  | 1      | f
1460  | 1452   | publisher
2456  | 1460   | appname
3456  | 2456   | url
```

As you can see, each row contains a parent, which connects it to another row And they all end up connecting to parent 1 (This is the Microsoft [database](https://winget.azureedge.net/cache/source.msix) for Winget software) and If we put these rows together in order, it creates the specifications of a package for example:

```
h\microsoft\vscode\1.0.1.0\url.yml
```

I can extract this information with the following code

```
var query =
    from item in msixDB.IdsMSIXTable
    from manifest in msixDB.Set<ManifestMSIXTable>().Where(e => e.id == item.rowid)
    
    from yml in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == manifest.pathpart).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from pathPartVersion in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == yml.parent).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from pathPartAppName in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == pathPartVersion.parent).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from pathPartPublisher in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == pathPartAppName.parent).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from pathPart in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == pathPartPublisher.parent).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from version in msixDB.VersionsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == manifest.version).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new ManifestTable
    {
        PackageId = item.id,
        YamlName = $@"{pathPart.pathpart}\{pathPartPublisher.pathpart}\{pathPartAppName.pathpart}\{pathPartVersion.pathpart}\{yml.pathpart}",
        Version = version.version
    };

mydb.ManifestTable.AddRange(await query.ToListAsync());
```

But the problem is that these rows do not have a fixed number, so the code I wrote does not work.
For example, in the table above, as you can see, one of the packages contains 4 rows and the other contains 3 rows.
I need a way to follow the parent rows to reach parent 1 and extract the information.

Update:

```
[Table("pathparts")]
public class PathPartsMSIXTable
{
    [Key]
    public long rowid { get; set; }
    public long parent { get; set; }
    public string pathpart { get; set; }

}
```

UPDATE 2:

I slightly modified the code you wrote and it turned out as follows

```
from manifest in msixDB.Set<ManifestMSIXTable>().Where(e => e.id == item.rowid)

                from yml in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == manifest.pathpart)
                
                from pathPart in pathCte.Where(e => e.rowid == yml.parent && e.parent == null)
                from version in msixDB.VersionsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == manifest.version)
                select new ManifestTable
                {
                    PackageId = item.id,
                    YamlName = $@"{pathPart.path}\{yml.pathpart}",
                    Version = version.version
                };
```

Now everything is working fine Except that some rows have not been added

microsoft database

[image]

after adding items to database

[image]

As you can see, only 1 row has been added

---

UPDATE 3

I noticed that some items are stored duplicated in the database, How can I prevent duplicate information based on ID and version number?
I used the **Distinct** method but got an error

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Sequence 'value(LinqToDB.EntityFrameworkCore.LinqToDBForEFToolsDataConnection).GetTable().SelectMany(item => value(LinqToDB.EntityFrameworkCore.LinqToDBForEFToolsDataConnection).GetTable().Where(e => (e.id == item.rowid)), (item, manifest) => new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(item = item, manifest = manifest)).SelectMany(<>h__TransparentIdentifier0 => value(LinqToDB.EntityFrameworkCore.LinqToDBForEFToolsDataConnection).GetTable().Where(e => (e.rowid == <>h__TransparentIdentifier0.manifest.pathpart)), (<>h__TransparentIdentifier0, yml) => new <>f__AnonymousType1`2(<>h__TransparentIdentifier0 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier0, yml = ...
```

[image]

```
query = query.Distinct(new GenericCompare<ManifestTable>(x => x.PackageId));
            var data = await query.ToArrayAsyncLinqToDB();
            mydb.AddRange(data);
```

Comment: I had feeling that you have chosen bad ORM for your task. You need CTE for this situation. If you OK, I'll prepare sample with this extension: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore, note that I'm creator of this extension.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have not worked with the database much, so I do not enough, I'm OK

Comment: Could you update question with `PathPartsMSIXTable` class definition?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such task you need Recursive CTE which is not supported by EF any version. I have proposed usage of extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) which can bring such functionality into existing EF Core projects.

```cs
class PathCte
{
    public long rowid { get; set; }
    public long? parent { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
using var msixDB = new MSIXContext();

var mydb = new HWGContext();

await mydb.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
await mydb.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

using var db = msixDB.CreateLinqToDbConnection();

var pathCte = db.GetCte<PathCte>(cte => (
        from pathPart in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable
        select new PathCte
        {
            rowid = pathPart.rowid,
            parent = pathPart.parent,
            path = pathPart.pathpart
        }
    )
    .Concat(
        from pathPart in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable
        from child in cte.Where(child => child.parent == pathPart.rowid)
        select new PathCte
        {
            rowid = child.rowid,
            parent = pathPart.parent,
            path = pathPart.pathpart + "\\" + child.path
        }       
    )
);

var query =
    from item in msixDB.IdsMSIXTable
    from manifest in msixDB.Set<ManifestMSIXTable>().Where(e => e.id == item.rowid)

    from yml in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == manifest.pathpart)
    from pathPartVersion in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == yml.parent)
    from pathPartAppName in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == pathPartVersion.parent)
    from pathPartPublisher in msixDB.PathPartsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == pathPartAppName.parent)

    from pathPart in pathCte.Where(e => e.rowid == pathPartPublisher.parent && e.parent == null)
    from version in msixDB.VersionsMSIXTable.Where(e => e.rowid == manifest.version)
    select new ManifestTable
    {
        PackageId = item.id,
        YamlName = $@"{pathPart.path}\{pathPartPublisher.pathpart}\{pathPartAppName.pathpart}\{pathPartVersion.pathpart}\{yml.pathpart}",
        Version = version.version
    };

var data = await query.ToArrayAsyncLinqToDB();

mydb.AddRange(data);
await mydb.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Also do I have to use `LinqToDBForEFTools.Initialize();`?

Comment: Thank you, but i got an error in `mydb.BulkCopy(query.ToLinqToDB());`  `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: manifests.Id'.'`, also i changed `int` to `long` in `PathCte`

Comment: i added `.Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()` to the end of the lines now I get another error `Database do not support CROSS/OUTER APPLY join required by the query.
`

Comment: 1) You. can use EF SaveChanges. 2) Why you have added Take(1).DeefaultIfEmpty()?

Comment: i should remove `mydb.BulkCopy` and use SaveChanges? This question is a continuation of my previous question that you answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67900436/improve-efcore-query-for-fast-operation/67902466#67902466 So I added it based on your previous answer

Comment: Yes, try to use SaveChanges, I have no your classes definition to check why BulkCopy do not work.

Comment: not worked again and i got an error System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.' i uploaded my classes and database file here https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/files/6628967/Database.zip

Comment: thank you, Everything works fine except that some items are not added to the database I updated my question, please check if possible

Comment: ManifestMSIXTable contains 6668 items, result contains 6668 items. I do not follow your logic.

Comment: I'm a little confused, now that I've checked again, your code has extracted all the information correctly, Because I manually extracted publisher, program name and the version number, and you used this information (publisher) in the pathpart to extract the information. So I felt that this method might be wrong, and it would be better to identify the rest of the parents by yml.parent

Comment: thank you again, my problem completly solved

Comment: I noticed that some items are stored duplicated in the database, How can I prevent duplicate information based on ID and version number? i Updated my question please see it